# Where do I override the create_export_query for a custom module?

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I am working with SugarCRM.

I have a custom module, I am trying to override the export method to not include all of the columns. I actually need to make the columns dependent on the visible columns in the list view (that I can figure out).

I have been going through all the files in SugarCRM, I notice that the built in modules have a Module.php file, where there is a `'SELECT Module.*'` for the export method. I cannot find a file like that for my custom module. I am asking for help on where do I create (if needed) or where can I find the file to customize the create_export_query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`create_export_query` is a method in SugarBean (`/data/SugarBean.php` is the base class for nearly all SugarCRM objects) and can be overriden in the bean's core class file. So if you have custom module `MyModule` you can find the core class in `/modules/MyModule/MyModule.php`

There is likely not a create_export_query() method there currently, so you can write one in. It'll look something like this:

```
<?php
require_once("include/SugarObjects/templates/basic/Basic.php");
class MyModule extends Basic{

  public function MyModule(){
    parent::Basic();
  }

  public function create_export_query(&$order_by, &$where, $relate_link_join=''){
    $query = " select * from {$this->table_name} "; // build your query string however you like
    return $query;
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks like what I want to do. I have been trying this all weekend, and am still a little lost. I can see this going in Two different places. /custom/modulebuilder/packages/pkg/modules/myModule and /custom/modules/myModules - does it matter?

Comment: It matters very much, but both locations you mention are wrong. `/custom/modulebuilder/` represents the module you've made using Module Builder but it isn't yet deployed. It's like a staging area. You'll need to make these changes to your core module post-deployment, so if you haven't deployed your module yet go ahead and do so. Then go straight into `/modules/MyModule/MyModule.php`. When editing a module's core class, don't go into `/custom` at all.