# Exporting relationship fields in Leads Module

Tags: php, sugarcrm, sugarbean

In Leads module, I have One-to-Many relationships called `leads_assigned_user` and `campaign_leads`. The first one is a user assigned to a lead and the second one is a campaign associated with a lead. In List view, the assigned user is shown as a column with the full name of the user, and the campaign is the name of a campaign. When I export Leads to a CSV, the assigned user is exported as the user's name. But, the campaign is exported as the campaign's ID, which is not at all user-friendly. Where can I find the code that forces the assigned user to be exported as a name and the campaign to be exported as ID?

I need to modify the exporting process to export the campaign as a name. Some [recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919229/where-do-i-override-the-create-export-query-for-a-custom-module) for doing this involve overriding the `create_export_query` method in SugarBean.php. Is this the best way to do it? If so, where should I place the overriding code? Should this code be an extension of the SugarBean class?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What version of Sugar? And did you try using Reports for generating the CSV? There you can select e.g. the "name" field of a related record as output column.

Comment: I'm using Sugar 8.1 Yes, using the Reports does work, but I'm trying to find a way to export Leads without having to use the Reports because this adds an extra step that should not be necessary.

Comment: Hm, I see. Not sure how to solve this yet. However, here's a orkaround-suggestion: You could create a custom field (type: text) in studio and give it a formula for retrieving the linked campain's there (e.g. `related($campaigns`, "name")`) and just use that field's output in the CSV. Note: You'll have to recalculate/resave all existing datasets to apply the formula the first time.

Comment: That worked great, thank you! No need for code changes after all.